# Issue with integrating wallet connect v2, which version is supported as of now?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am using the following walletconnect dependencies:
"@walletconnect/ethereum-provider": "^2.9.2",
"@walletconnect/modal": "^2.6.1",

After copying the walletconnect link and pasting on https://app.safe.global/apps/,
I get the following message on the safe wallet web app:

We were unable to create a connection due to compatibility issues with the latest WalletConnect v2 upgrade. We are actively working with the WalletConnect team and the dApps to get these issues resolved. Use Safe Apps instead wherever possible. Related screenshot:
[image]

Guide me on what version of walletconnect I can use to get it wor